# how to enable a submit button when div index bigger than 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, indexing

i have a question in jquery, i can add div  dynamically and when max index of div is bigger than 2 i want enable the submit button which is disabled before, these are some of the code but i dont kown how it can work?

```
if ("max index of div biger than 2") {
        $('input[disabled="disabled"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('input[disabled="disabled"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```

i dont kown how to write the condition in jquery

**thank you for all the response, my code is if($('div.radio').length > 0), i have a class "radio" to distinguish with others, now it works!!!but**

for delete, i use

```
<div class="radio">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.IsRight,true)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.Name)<a class="option_delete" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();"></a><br />
</div>
```

but as u see, the delete function cant delete the div with class="radio", i delete the div when the index of div=0, but the submit button is still enabled..i want the submit button to be disabled when i delete div untile the index of div = 0

Comment: what do you mean by index

Comment: What about `if($('.selector').length > 2) { ... }`?

Comment: the index of div, i click a button, it will add a <div>test</div>for ex, with index 0, and i click button again, add another<div>test</div>,with index 1,i want click until index>2 and then enable the submit button which is disabled before

Comment: Divs don't have indexes, what do you mean by that? By index do you mean the number of the div when you count children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just count the `divs` using `.length`

```
if ($('div').length => 2) {
        $('input[disabled="disabled"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('input[disabled="disabled"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```

Comment: this would disable all inputs if there are 2 or more divs on the page; I don't think that's the question

Comment: well thats what the op wrote - what is the question then? :)

Comment: how to disable the inputs that are children of divs whose index is greater than 1, this should leave the inputs of the first 2 div's enabled... right? or am I misunderstanding?